# AWS-ALB not forwarding traffic to newly added backend pods on EKS

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have 2 separate deployments on EKS. The first one takes messages from the redis queue, does some processing and calls the second service running behind an internal Amazon ALB.

Problem : While scaling the application, both services are scaled independently. But the problem is once the pods for the first service have been scaled up, the newly added pods for the second service aren't receiving any traffic. Is there a setting problem in ALB or something else?

Comment: Why are you not using Kubernetes Services to achieve the load balancing. If both apps are deployed to the same EKS Cluster this should work. How are you handling the ingress? Are you using the AWS Load Balancer Controller for that?

Comment: I started with kubernetes services initially but load balancing was happening on L4 and i wanted it on L7 hence, used a load balancer. Yes i am using ingress controller for handling ingress

Comment: What [target-type](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/latest/guide/ingress/annotations/#target-type) are you using? Can you share the logs of the AWS Load Balancer Controller. It should add newly created targets to the target group. If that does not work, there might be an IAM policy missing in the service account.